# Indian National Olympiad $2006$ Problem $2$

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$ there exists a unique ordered pair $(a,b)$ of positive integers such that
> $n = \frac{1}{2}(a + b - 1)(a + b - 2) + a .$

**My sol outline** -

I used induction for proving that there exist a pair for any $n$

for $n=1$ ,we get easily that $(1,1)$ only pair,

Now assume it is true for some $n=k$,let the pair in this case be $(a,b)=(l,m)$

Case1) - if $m=1$ then for $n=k+1$ we have $(a,b)=(l,l+1)$
Case2) - if $m$ is not 1 then for $n=k+1$ we have $(a,b)=(l+1,m-1)$

hence for any n we have a pair.

Now since for $n=1$ we have only one pair i.e $(1,1)$ (which can be proved easily)
so for any other $n$ greater than $1$ ,we should have only one pair otherwise we can apply the above rule to generate the previous solutions for lesser values of n ,but $n=1$ has only one solution so it is impossible.

**Is there any mistake in above solution** ?

thankyou

Comment: You have a typo: $(a,b)=(l,l+1)$ in Case 1 should be $(a,b)=(1,l+1)$.

Comment: Apart from this, your proof works, I think; but it would be improved if you wrote out the inverse transformation (the solution for $n-1$) explicitly, to show that it is uniquely defined.

Comment: @TonyK ok,thanks